# Flex Tree open items issue

Tags: apache-flex, tree

In the Flex Tree, when I open a tree item, all its sub items are opened, too. I know they weren't open before because I closed them, and then closed the parent and opened it again.
Does anyone know how to solve that? Is there a property of the tree I have to change?
Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help you unless you provide some code.

Comment: This is a UI component behavior question, not an issue I have with my code.